# Using SVG create a transparent diagonal cut

Tags: css, svg

I'm currently using clip-path on the image below. I stupidly didn't look at the browser support and found that it does not work in Edge or IE 11.

I'm wondering how or if possible I could create the below effect with just an SVG that will be supported in IE 11 and Edge.

[image]

I currently have been playing around with the below code but strugglign to understand how I can put a image over it like the image above.

```
    <svg>
      <path d="M0,60 L50,0 L420,0 A56,56 0 20,1 470,60z" fill="red" />
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <text x="410" y="37" font-size="18" font-weight="500" fill="yellow">Test</text>
      </a>
    </svg>
```

Really looking forward to your ideas.

Comment: I would drop actual masking and fake the whole visual outcome with rectangles and SVGs as `background-image`s. Having the hero image as a full layer and covering it with the tilted menu looks quite reasonable.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean tbh. Would you be able to show a simple example?

Comment: I believe @mystrdat is asking why the photo needs to be masked at all. Why can't you just arrange the black areas on top of it?

Comment: Plus there are other alternatives to clip paths. For instance, CSS masks, or SVG shapes with a `<mask>`, `<clipPath>` or `<pattern>`

Comment: ahhhhh I'm with you guys now. I do still need the diagonal line though so how would i put that on the rectangles

Comment: Check this visual - https://i.imgur.com/0sHsGu4.png
If you approach the navigation as a rect and the diagonal line as separate layer (which can be SVG or bitmap backgrounds), you can cover the hero image and get the intended outcome working everywhere.

Comment: Alternatively instead of a single background, the edge of the diagonal (as is in the topmost layer) can be a separate element that is "pushed" to the left by the menu entries, which means you would only need one small SVG object to create the effect, although it means you would need to use exact sizes for the diagonal to be continous. Example: https://i.imgur.com/23r20CR.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough idea (sorry for rough code as made it in a hurry) using pseudo elements `::before` & `::after` along with css3 transform and transition properties to achieve somewhat the result you are looking for. You can check it out and work around it if it helps. I checked it in FF and IE edge and 11 and 10 and it works well overall.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/EvEMMG

Hope this helps gives your the idea or a work around the issue.